# Images inside react native FlatList fade in instead of just being prerendered

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that renders a bunch of images but they fade in as I'm scrolling instead of being already rendered. I thought that the windowSize prop of FlatList makes it so that some stuff is already rendered outside the view port.

```
 <FlatList
          windowSize={8}
          numColumns={columns}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={4}
          data={cardObjects}
          renderItem={itemRender}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        />
```

The Image component looks like:

```
  <Image
      source={{
        uri: props.uri,
      }}
      style={{width: '100%', aspectRatio: ASPECT_RATIO}}
    />
```

I want the images to be already rendered such that when you scroll down it's already there.

Currently it behaves like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFFmrAHwAQk

Answer (score 1):

Flatlist renders only items that are on screen.

You can pre-render by using these 2 props

```js
initialNumToRender={20}
maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
```

One more optimization when it comes to rendering images in list [`react-native-fast-image`](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) as recommended in [official docs in react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#use-cached-optimized-images)